# javascript - swap url for download link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a simple html site where at the top is a main image with a download button.
The download works with the html5 download attribute.

Now i have some thumbnails underneath the main image - which when clicked replace the main image with the thumbnail image.

Following issue: I use the same javascript code to also replace the url of the download button with the thumbnails url, but when clicking the download button it still opens the hardcoded download link from the html instead of using the replaced url.

HTML

```
<div class="dwnldcntnr">
 <img src="imgage1.jpg" alt="Image Title 1" />
  </div>

<div id="btncntnr">
 <a href="imgage/image1.jpg" download="image1.jpg">
 <button id="btn">Download</button></a>
  </div>

<div class="itemcntnr">
 <a href="image2.jpg" title="2.jpg">
 <img src="image2.jpg" />
  </a></div>
```

JS code for replacing download url with thumbnail url

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.itemcntnr a').click(function() {
        var path = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#btncntnr a').attr('href', path)
                             .attr('download', $('a', this).attr('title'));
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I guess `$('a', this).attr('title')` should be `$(this).attr('title')`. And, since you are using HTML5, go for data-attributes to store your datas http://api.jquery.com/data/ . title is not for storing variables

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the whole DOM element.

I don't think you should be nesting a `button` inside an `a` tag, as they're both elements that have native interactivity. You'll most likely come across HTML parsing errors in earlier versions of IE.

```
$('.itemcntnr a').click(function() {
    var $this = $this.clone().empty().html('Download');
    $('#btncntnr a').replaceWith($this);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks for the help, however replacing the js doesnt solve the problem.  i will consider changing the button inside a, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @D.M - Sorry I just realised there was an error in my code (I was referencing `$(this)` instead of the created variable `$this`). Try again with the above.

Comment: still nothing :/ its so weird because my code totally works with replacing the images onclick but not with the href.

Comment: @D.M - I just realised the cloned element doesn't have a `download` attribute. Try adding that in?

Answer (score 0):

Don't put hard coded href for the link in html instead try to add it on `$(document).ready`

Also I agree with ahren that you should never put `button` inside an `a` tag. Instead apply styles to `a` tag so that it will look like a button

Comment: the hardcoded href is there because the main image needs to have its download url when the page is opened.

Comment: Thats right, it does require the download url. But being hardcoded it might get cached try to put it on document.ready function as `$('#btncntnr a').attr('href', 'imgage/image1.jpg')`

Comment: thanks for the fiddle. It seems like its not working in my code because there is a conflict between the image swap code and the url swap code. I use each script seperately, so its working when i delete the script for the image swap, but i need both. Any ideas?

Comment: thanks for all your time. In your fiddle there are 2 pop ups displaying + the images swap both. Here is a fiddle how i used to do it, there you can see the image behaviour i already got working http://jsfiddle.net/f6n8J/ .

Comment: Any idea how i can use the same image behaviour like in the fiddle i posted above and make the url change at the same time?

Comment: Check the http://jsfiddle.net/Rr7F4/7/ code carefully you will get your answer. It is working the way you want it to be.

Comment: i was blinded by my newbiness. but i think i figured it out now. Thanks gjdev.tech

Comment: its ok but you should go through the answers properly and mark the one as answer which solved your problem so that others will be able to figure out answer to their queries

Comment: i still have a issue. When clicking, the code uses the image from <a href. But it should use the image from <img id"imgtoswap" src instead, because i want to change the thumbnail, not the full size picture which is under a href! So basically main image and imgtoswap are the thumbnails which should be changed, but the link opens the image in full size.